# Why wont form load call the code that initializes my graphics?

Tags: c#, startup, drawimage

So I'm back and I've got another issue concerning graphics.

I searched Google and also searched stackoverflow. I might not have been thorough enough, but I figured half an hour of no results means it's time to ask another question.

After getting past my graphical issue with DrawImage, now I'm having another issue linked to the same method call.

I have my form load code here

```
private void frmMapEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loadComponents();
            Program.debug.print("Load complete.");
        }
```

And I have this code in loadComponents

```
private void loadComponents()
    {
        Rectangle srcRectTiles = new Rectangle(0, 0, 16 * 16, 20 * 16);
        GraphicsUnit units = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;

        screenTiles.DrawImage(gfxTiles, 0, 0, srcRectTiles, units);
    }
```

Now, I've made sure the graphics work by calling Load() in a Click() event, and the code runs just fine. It's just when I run the game and expect to see something on load, nothing happens. The debug code you see there displays the output "Load complete." after Load() is ran (to make sure it is indeed being called), but it doesn't seem to be running the actual code inside loadComponents(). I've even added debug code to that method, and they print their outputs in the console accordingly...

Any insight would be wonderful! I can offer more code if necessary. Maybe there's a way of debugging this I'm not quite catching onto.

Comment: Where do you get the `gfxTiles` graphics object, and why don't you [draw in the Paint event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: That did it. Hmm... I wonder why. Never ran across anything like that. Thanks. Still very new to Windows Programming in C#. Excuse my ignorance. :)

Comment: That's why I asked where you got the graphics object. :) See [How to: Create Graphics Objects for Drawing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y289054(v=vs.110).aspx). Also, if you're building a game, you might want to dump GDI(+) as soon as possible for its horrible performance. :) Depends on the game though.

Comment: Well thanks for the tips. Just starting off with C# programming. Why not try with a game, right? Haha. It is declared in the form's class member space, then initialized in the constructor. I'll do some more reading. And GDI performance wise hasn't been giving me many issues. Testing 1200 16 x 16 tiles being painted happened in less than a second, which is more than enough for me I think. I just don't know any other graphics libraries I can use with such ease, at least for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try calling the `loadComponents()` method in form's `Shown` event.

Comment: This still didn't work, as clever as an idea it was.